# Execute all .bat files in the current folder and delete them after execution

Tags: c#, multithreading, batch-file

I am a newbie programmer wanting to make averaging videos. I have made a program to create n .bat files doing the average of n images, now I would like to execute them as fast as possible.

The .bat files are independent.
I am in a Windows environment.

I have looked at C# multi threading (threadpool, parrallel.for, parralel.foreach etc), but none of the functions there seems to work. I have no illusion that it's me who's doing something wrong though.

Powershell has a function doing what I want, but only for other powershell commands.

The code I have now that mostly works is: 
(complete solution at https://github.com/Madsfoto/ParallelExecutionForEach )

```
var paths = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*.bat"); // have a list of all .bat files in the current directory
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; // above is to not see the cmd window

            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); // It's easier than having to specify where this program will be run.



Parallel.ForEach(paths, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, currentFile => // 4 is set because I have 4 cores to use
                {
                    proc.StartInfo.FileName = currentFile; // Set the currentfile as the one being executed. currentFile is the name of the .bat file to execute
    proc.Start(); // execute the .bat file
                        proc.WaitForExit();
                    File.Delete(currentFile);
                });
```

I get `System.InvalidOperationException: No process is associated with this object` and `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`’s when I run more than 3-4 processes at the same time.

I suspect that it is the WaitForExit() that is giving me problems, but do not have the skills to debug it.

I have looked at Threading.Task as well, but my skill is not good enough to use it.

So the solution I am after is as follows:

*Execute either 1 input file with x lines of independent action or x files with 1 action, with a limit of y processes at the same time either set at compile or runtime.*
Programming language is not important to me, although my preference is understandable C#.

(The result is something like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ph6-6bYTgs0, with n frames averaged together)

Comment: Test files: https://mega.nz/#!CUowlBYT!IhqGdtILO7fvcgE2H1wycfXWd1W8PmSx1-lvHCKlo0c (click download through your browswer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to move the

```
proc.Start(); // execute the .bat file
proc.WaitForExit();
try
{
   File.Delete(FileName);
}
catch
{
}
```

code into it's own function (with the bookkeeping stuff (defining proc etc)).

The File.Delete() was the culprit, it turns out that there might be a bug in the Parallel.ForEach, but I have been unable to reproduce it reliably (experimenting gives errors ~0.01% of the time), but this way it works. It does require people to rerun the executable, but that is a burden I can justify pushing to the user.

The [github](https://github.com/Madsfoto/ParallelExecutionForEach/commit/4576db4da90157ddb99ff2741a8ed639d29c0e2a) link has been updated with a working version.